# Jasper Studio 6.0.3 create one table with multiple querys

Tags: jasper-reports

I have the following problem:

I need to fill a table with a fix size where each cell as is own query

Example: A table with columns A, B e C and lines E, F, G. For every match line/column i need to execute a specified query.

Can it be done ??

Comment: Question is unclear. Show screenshot of desired report with data

Answer (score 0):

There is issue that one table can have one dataset => one query. You can send the external parameters to the tables from for example report dataset, but it is not solution for many queries.

Is it possible to create an view in db which will cover your requirements and then display this view in report? this can be probably the best way how to handle this problem if you want to have all in one table.